# I have trouble with update python webpage (invalid password)

Tags: google-app-engine

I not update my web page about many days. I cant migrate to python27 etc.

I can't make $./appcfg.py update [my web page]

When I loging i get invalid password. I can login web engine on appspot.com

```
 Invalid username or password.
 2014-11-04 13:05:54,237 ERROR appcfg.py:2417 An error occurred processing file '': HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized. Aborting. 
 Error 401: --- begin server output ---
 Must authenticate first.
 --- end server output ---
```

Where I can send my trouble, how change this password not change web engine appspot password?

Comment: Are you using the password that belongs to the account with which you log into the appengine console?

Comment: Yes, I use this password. I can log in into my account on web. I can see Dasboard etc. I must migrate but can't update / upload my data

Comment: In the appcfg.py console, are you prompted for username and password? Or is it stored somewhere

Comment: Yes, I'm prompted: ~/google_appengine/appcfg.py --email=my@email update myweb/
 01:27 PM Application: aaaaaa; version: 1
 01:27 PM Host: appengine.google.com
 01:27 PM 
 Starting update of app: aaaaa, version: 1
 01:27 PM Getting current resource limits.
 Password for aaaaa@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:

Comment: I use this engine from 4 years. I never have trouble with it. This is free account. Is any chat irc etc places to talking about my trouble?

Comment: That is very strange. I would try to contact google about this issue

Comment: What I can to do? Where I can send my trouble? Can You know any e-mail etc.?

Comment: In the console overview, in the menu all the way on the bottom there is a `Need help?` link, click that

Comment: in https://appengine.google.com/ ? I noo have any that link . Is help but only for phone. I have free account

Comment: https://console.developers.google.com/

Answer (score 2):

Give it a try with the `--oauth2` parameter, i.e. `appcfg.py --oauth2 update /path/to/your/app`

This will prompt for your credentials in the browser instead and will remember them for the next time in cookies so you don't have to do it again.

It will work as long as the account you entered the credentials for has access to the APP-ID you are trying to update.